# OpenVPN 503 behind http proxy

Tags: openvpn, tcp, squid, ubuntu-18.04

I have a OpenVPN server successfully setup on a digital ocean droplet following this amazing tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Then I also made a http proxy server using squid proxy on a different droplet.

When I try to connect to my VPN server, I get 503 Service Unavailable on the logs of the client. Also when I try to curl my VPN server, still the same result:

curl -I -x myproxy.com:80 http://myvpn.com:1194 or curl -I -x myproxy.com:80 http://myvpn.com

I turned off the ufw of my OpenVPN server, still the same results.

Where should I fix? My OpenVPN server? My My OpenVPN server's iptables? My squid proxy conf?

Please help..

OpenVPN server config.

server.conf

```
port 1194

proto udp


dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  

dh dh.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

verb 3

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

client.conf

```
client

dev tun

proto tcp

remote rl.rltech.xyz 1194 # domain I attached to my vpn server


resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

http-proxy proxy.rltech.xyz 80 # domain I attached my proxy server (squid proxy running on port 80)
http-proxy-retry
http-proxy-timeout 5
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER Host www.googlevideo.com
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER X-Forwarded-For www.googlevideo.com




ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key

remote-cert-tls server


tls-auth ta.key 1


cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1

verb 3

;mute 20

; script-security 2
; up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
; down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
; script-security 2
; up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
; down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
; down-pre
; dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
cert here ..
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

iptables.sh (the only rules on my VPN Server)

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Proxy server

squid.conf

```
acl SSL_ports port 1194      # OpenVPN
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 1194      # OpenVPN
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
dns_nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
http_access allow all
http_port 80
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Comment: I can connect normally if I change the protocol of the client.conf to udp and remove http proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/connecting-to-an-openvpn-server-via-an-http-proxy/) you must use TCP with the http-proxy directive so try to set `proto tcp` in both server and client config

Comment: Just added that code on my existing squid.conf file sir, still the same results.

Comment: According to the documentation here [link](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/connecting-to-an-openvpn-server-via-an-http-proxy/) you must use TCP with the `http-proxy` directive so try to set `proto tcp` in both server and client config

Comment: Thanks sir, your comment solved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my previous answer so please mark it as accepted and delete your answser to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As per @demathos

I deployed another instance of openvpn server, now running is:
openvpn@server - 1194/udp
openvpn@server1 - 1194/tcp

```
netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      733/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24288/openvpn
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      733/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      20175/(squid-1)
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           616/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33916           0.0.0.0:*                           20175/(squid-1)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           19762/openvpn
udp6       0      0 :::33573                :::*                                20175/(squid-1)
```

Comment: My client now can connect using the config above. Thank you. Solved.